# React native share:-how to use share functionality with different message for different app

Tags: react-native

I have a requirement in share functionality in which i want to share different different messages for facebook twitter and other apps. But in react native share i have only one message variable in which we pass the data. Can anyone help me about how to pass different message in different apps. Like how i can identify that facebook is selected or twitter is selecr or other app is selected and then send specific message to. That app in react native.
Please help me i am new to react native. It will be a great help.